# Deleting single MySQL row with HTML and Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, sql, node.js

I am trying to implement a way to delete a chosen row from my table. There is a `Delete` link at the end of each row which when clicked is meant to delete that row. When I run it and click the `Delete` link it does nothing. I don't get any errors, the console says `0 row(s) updated` and the row remains. Not sure what I'm missing.

```js
app.get('/device-list', function (req, res) {
  // query database to get all the devices
  let sqlquery = 'SELECT * FROM devices';

  // execute sql query
  db.query(sqlquery, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
    res.render('device-list.html', { availableDevices: result });
  });
});

app.get('/delete/:id', function (req, res, next) {
  var sql = 'DELETE FROM devices WHERE id = ?';
  var id = req.body.id;

  db.query(sql, [id], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(result.affectedRows + ' row(s) updated');
  });
  res.redirect('/device-list');
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Room</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% availableDevices.forEach(function(device){ %>
    <tr>
      <td><%=device.Name %></td>
      <td><%=device.Type %></td>
      <td><%=device.Room %></td>
      <td><a href="/edit/<%=device.id%>">Edit</a></td>
      <td><a href="/delete/<%=device.id%>">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    <% }) %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You are expecting an ID to come from both params and body. app.get('/delete', function(){}). Rest the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the id as a route [parameter](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) not as a part of a body.
So you should access it using the params property.

```
 var id = req.params.id;
```

Give it a try

Comment: On the other hand, id is not passed to params in the ejs file. therefore, id will be undefined.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I changed the variable to your solution but now it shows 'Cannot GET /delete/20'. I'm not sure how to correct this?

Comment: Did you change the route or is there a typo anywhere? Cannot GET happens when the route is not specified. The code I posted should not have affected it.

Comment: [Here](https://www.anyfiddle.com/p/esszed/cr7f3jpe) is an example of it working on any fiddle. You can see that the id is getting passed correctly as a param.

Comment: I had to completely exit my VM and reconnect and it suddenly works now. Thanks a lot that was my bad